# how to skip Hyperterminal splash page (spinning globe)

Tags: windows-7, windows, serial-port, rs232

Is there a secret trick to skipping the 5 second animated splash screen when Hilgraeve HYPERTERMINAL starts?

When I open HyperTerminal (HyperTrm.exe), I want it to open immediately, and not show me that the world is still going 'round.

v7.0 still has this annoying 'feature.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HERE IS SOLUTION:
I emailed Hilgraeve support, and he sent a special .dll that does NOT spin at boot.  Perfect!
Had a hick up or two getting it to run:  had to completely uninstall the old one, yada, yada